# why if I use ng-repeat, the jQ plugin doesn't work, if don't use, it work normal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use semantic-ui in angular
when I don't use ng-repeat in html, jQuery plugin work normal
like this

**html**

```
  <div class="ui animate list">
    <div class="item ui toggle checkbox" todo-checkbox>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>222</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**directive.js**

```
  todoApp.directive('todoCheckbox', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.checkbox();
      }
    };
  });
```

if my code like this, The checkbox plugin work normal

but if I use `ng-repeat` in html, `elem.checkbox()`inoperative like this

```
<div class="ui animate list">
  <div class="item ui toggle checkbox" todo-checkbox ng-repeat="item in day track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label ng-bind="item.content"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `directive.js` is same as abve

if use `ng-repeat`, app isn't work,
why?
how can I fixed this?

Comment: What errors are being shown in the console?

Comment: there is no error show in console.......